# Optimization of a function of 4 variables under constraint

Tags: optimization

I am currently trying to solve my own optimality problem.

Let $f :(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R^4} \mapsto 1 + d_1+d_2+d_3+d_4+d_5 \in \mathbb{R}_+$ where:

$d_1 = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

$d_2= \sqrt{c^2+d^2}$

$d_3=\sqrt{(a-1)^2+b^2}$

$d_4=\sqrt{(c-1)^2+d^2}$

$d_5=\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}$

I would like to know what methods can we use to find the minimum value $m$ of $f$ knowing that $\forall i \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}, d_i \geq1$?

For now, I have shown geometrically that $5+\sqrt{3} \geq m >6$. I am not looking necessarily for a full answer but rather for methods to deal with that kind of problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [LocalSolver](https://www.localsolver.com) to tackle your problem:

```
function model() {
    lowerBound = -100;  //  somewhat arbitrary
    upperBound = +100;

    a <- float(lowerBound, upperBound);
    b <- float(lowerBound, upperBound);
    c <- float(lowerBound, upperBound);
    d <- float(lowerBound, upperBound);

    d1 <- sqrt2(a, b);
    d2 <- sqrt2(c, d);
    d3 <- sqrt2(a - 1, b);
    d4 <- sqrt2(c - 1, d);
    d5 <- sqrt2(a - c, b - d);
    
    constraint d1 >= 1.0;
    constraint d2 >= 1.0;
    constraint d3 >= 1.0;
    constraint d4 >= 1.0;
    constraint d5 >= 1.0;

    m <- 1 + d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5;

    minimize m;
}

function sqrt2(u, v) {
    return pow(u*u + v*v, 0.5);
}
```

The result:

```
m=6.73204901816782

a=0.499997511563293
b=-0.866027201892499
c=1.49999583752018
d=-0.866027201892499

d1=1.00000031299357
d2=1.73204810181347
d3=1.0000028014264
d4=0.999999475977494
d5=0.999998325956891

elapsed 0.211s
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is 100% coherent with my intuitive vision of this problem, indeed we end up with $m = 5 +\sqrt{3} \approx 6.73205$.

Comment: Have you any idea/methods for proof?

Comment: The constraints are looking like a geometric problem of rectangular triangles. Variables `a`, `b` and `d1` could be seen as side lengths of one triangle. Similarly, other triangles are described by `c`, `d`, `d2`, and so on. The constraints put on `d1`, ... `d5` could be modelled as circles. Further than that, I do not have a proof to add.

Comment: That's right. You can check the original problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775947/geometry-and-optimization-in-a-plane. Thank you for introducing LocalSolver, it looks like a great tool. Have a nice day.