# Minimizing the sum of the six distances determined by four points in the plane, if each distance is at least $d$

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

My problem is as follows:

> Consider four points $A,B,C,D$ in a plane. Let's call $P$ the proximity defined by
> $$P =AB+AC+AD+BC+BD+CD$$ There is one constraint: each point must be at least at an Euclidean distance $d$ from the other points.
>
> I want to know what configuration makes $P$ minimal, and most importantly I would like to prove it.

My intuitive guess for the moment is the following configuration (here $d=1$):

[image]

In that configuration $P = (5+\sqrt{3})d$. (Furthermore it is easy to show that $P>6d$).
Thus, if this configuration seems the best possible I don't have any clue on how to prove this result for the moment. Therefore any help would be appreciated.

**Edit** : I know that this is the best configuration, and that thanks to numerical solver as the one used by LinAlg (c.f. answer below). But this is for me incomplete, I don't want any assistance of a numerical solver to prove the result.

Comment: Make the circles around each point $d/2$ radius, not $d$ -- it will be a packing problem.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I would love more details on packing problem and how it relates to my problem, could you provide me some please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I give an alternative solution without numerical solvers.

The four points form a quadrangle. Let me first show that the optimal configuration forms a convex quadrangle. A configuration of four points in which no order of the vertices forms a convex quadrangle is a triangle with a point on the inside, see picture below:

[image: concave configuration]

Suppose first that one of the three diagonals has a length larger than $d$. Without loss generality, assume that $CD$ has a length larger than $d$. At least one of the sides $AC$ and $BC$ has a length larger than $d$. If not, the four points form a convex quadrangle.
Without loss of generality, assume that $AC$ has length larger than $d$. By rotating $C$ around $B$ towards $A$ we reduce $AC$ and $CD$; hence the configuration is not minimal.

So we can assume that all three diagonals have length $d$, so we are in a configuration of three isosceles triangles with equal sides $d$.

At least one of the sides of the triangle has a length larger than $d$, otherwise one of the diagonals has length smaller than $d$. So assume  without loss of generality that $AC$ is the largest of the three outside edges. This means that the angle $ADC$ is at least $\frac{2\pi}{3}$; hence $AC$ is at least $\sqrt{3}d$.
If $AC > \sqrt{3}d$, then $P > 5d + \sqrt{3}d$; which is not minimal because you have found a better configuration.
If $AC=\sqrt{3}d$, then at least one of the angles $CDB$ and $ADB$ is $\geq \frac{2\pi}{3}$. So at least one side of $BC$ and $AB$ has length $\geq \sqrt{3}d$. This means that $P \geq 4d + 2\sqrt{3}d > d(5 + \sqrt{3})$. This proves that this configuration is not minimal.
This shows that in the minimal configuration the four points form a convex quadrangle.

---

Now I prove that in the minimal configuration, the four points form a rhombus. If three sides are of length $d$ and one side has length larger than $d$, then we can shorten this side by one of the following actions:

- By only moving $A$, rotating $A$ around $B$.
- By only moving $D$, rotating $D$ around $C$.

The first action is possible if $AC$ is larger than $d$ and the second action is possible if $BD$ is larger than $d$. If both $AC$ and $BD$ are equal to $d$, then $AD$ has length $d$ as well; therefore at least one of these actions is possible. The result of the actions is:

- Moving $A$: everything stays the same, except $AC$ and $AD$ reduce.
- Moving $D$: everything stays the same, except $BD$ and $AD$ reduce.

[image: One side larger than d]

This means that this configuration cannot be optimal.

Suppose now we have two adjacent sides of length $d$ and the other sides have length larger than $d$ (see picture below)

[image: two adjacent sides larger than d]

If we move $A$ on $AC$, while fixing the other points, then $AC$, $AB$, and $AD$ reduce in length, while the others stay the same. This action is only possible if $AC$ has length larger than $d$. If $AC$ has length $d$, then we can rotate $B$ around $C$ towards the diagonal $AC$ reducing the length of $AB$ and $BC$. Therefore, in all situations, this configuration cannot be optimal.

Suppose now we have two opposite sides of length $d$ and the other two sides have a length larger than $d$, see picture below.

[image: two opposite sides larger than d]

By simultaneously moving $A$ and $B$ (by the same speed) in a direction perpendicular to $CD$,  we decrease both diagonals and the sides $BC$ and $AD$. This action is only possible if both diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ have length larger than $d$. If one of the diagonals has length $d$ (without loss of generality assume that $AC$ has length $d$), then we can rotate $B$ around $A$ towards $AC$ to reduce the length of $BC$. This shows that in all cases that this configuration is not optimal.

Assume one side has length $d$ and all other sides have a length greater than $d$, see picture below.

[image: three sides larger than d]

If one of the diagonals has a length larger than $d$ (assume without loss of generality that $AC$ has length larger than $d$), then we can move $A$ on $AC$ towards $C$ to reduce the lengths of $AC$, $AB$, and $AD$.
If both diagonals have a length $d$, then $AB$ has a length $\leq d$, which is a contradiction. Therefore this situation cannot be minimal.

If all sides are larger than $d$, then at least on diagonal is larger than $d$. By moving the outer points of this diagonal inwards we get a better configuration; hence it is not minimal.

---

Therefore you can assume that the points form a rhombus with side length $d$. Take one angle $\alpha$ of this quadrangle (the other are $\pi-\alpha$, $\alpha$, and $\pi-\alpha$).

The length of the diagonals are $d\sqrt{2-2*\cos(\alpha)}$ and $d\sqrt{2+2*\cos(\alpha)}$ (see for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombus#Diagonals))

The diagonals are at least $d$ when $-\frac{1}{2} \leq \cos(\alpha) \leq \frac{1}{2}$; which is when $\frac{\pi}{3} \leq \alpha \leq \frac{2\pi}{3}$.

This means that to minimize $P$, we have to minimize $\sqrt{2-2*\cos(\alpha)} + \sqrt{2+2*\cos(\alpha)}$ on the interval $\left[\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{2\pi}{3}\right]$.

The second derivative (w.r.t. the variable $\alpha$) of this function is

$$\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sqrt{2-2\cos(\alpha)}} - \frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sqrt{2+2\cos(\alpha)}} - \frac{\sin^2(\alpha)}{(2-2\cos(\alpha))^{\frac{3}{2}}} - \frac{\sin^2(\alpha)}{(2+2\cos(\alpha))^{\frac{3}{2}}},$$

which is negative on the interval $\left[\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{2\pi}{3}\right]$.

Therefore the function to minimize is concave; hence the minimum is obtained at the border of the interval, i.e., $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{3}$ or $\alpha=\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Filling in one of those values for $\alpha$ we get that the minimum of $P$ is equal to

$$4d + d\sqrt{2-2\cos(\alpha_\min)} + d\sqrt{2+2\cos(\alpha_\min)} = d(5 + \sqrt{3}).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's the kind of approach I am looking for. While searching for my own problem, I have also shown that this was the best configuration for a rhombus. I will validate your answer if you can prove me rigorously that we can always minimize $P$ by making "the points form a rhombus with side length $d$".

Comment: @Axel I added the explanation why the points must form a rhombus.

Comment: It seems like the best answer so far. I don't see any contradiction yet. Thus I give you the bounty for your work. I'll take some time to double check everything just to make sure it is complete enough for me.

Comment: @Axel Let me know when something is not completely clear; I'll add extra clarifications (or corrections).

Comment: Once you assume that the optimum is a rhombus with sides of equal length, your analysis is right (except for the sign of the first derivative). Your answer is incomplete about getting there, for example in the first figure the three sides of length $d$ are drawn in a (mirrored) c-shape but they could also have a z-shape. Reducing the angle $\alpha$ might be impossible if the distance $AC$ is $d$. In the second figure, $C$ could be at the opposite side of $BD$. In the third figure, $BD$ can also be the first segment that hits the minimum distance limit when shifting $AB$.

Comment: @LinAlg You are right, I did not take time to check the second part as I already solved it. We do not really need the sign of the first derivative anyway. The second derivative is false (a sign is wrong) so from that form it is not immediate to guess the sign of the second derivative, I would appreciate a little bit more details for this part, I can post my own work for the second part as well.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen As LinAlg pointed out some work has to be done to make your answer more complete on the first part. I have the feeling that we are getting there but I am not yet totally convinced, It is still a little intuitive and I think it is maybe possible to be more rigorous.

Comment: @LinAlg I updated the answer to fix the errors, it has become a long answer.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen I've read your proof. Just minor things: you say "If both $AC$ and $BD$ are equal to $d$, then $AD$ is equal to $d$" but shouldn't it be $A$ is at the same position as $D$ or the quadrilateral is crossed? And what do you do if the quadrilateral is crossed? There is a typo at the end of first part proof: "one diagonal" not "on diagonal".  Otherwise it seems good enough, I won't ask for more. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Axel You are right about $A$ on the same position as $D$. The crossed case shouldn't be checked anymore, because we proved that the minimal configuration forms a convex quadrangle in the beginning. If there is still some parts unclear let me know, it is a rather fun proof.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen A concave quadrangle is different from a crossed one, right? Can't we just say that we rename the crossed quadrangle in order for it to be a convex one without loss of generality ?

Comment: @Axel With concave, I mean not convex. So a crossed one is concave. But indeed, the argument is indeed renaming the crossed quadrangle in order it to be a convex one without loss of generality.

Answer (score 2):

Let me phrase this as an optimization problem. There are at least two points that are distance $d$ apart, as otherwise you can contract the points and get a better solution. Let's assume point $A$ is at coordinate $(0,0)$ and $B$ is at $(0,d)$. So the challenge is to find points $C$ at $(v,w)$ and $D$ at $(x,y)$. I have phrased this as an optimization problem in AMPL format for $d=1$:

```
var v;
var w;
var x;
var y;

minimize total_distance: sqrt(v^2 + w^2) + sqrt(x^2+y^2) + sqrt(v^2+(w-1)^2) + sqrt(x^2+(y-1)^2) + sqrt((v-x)^2+(w-y)^2);
subject to min_dist_AC: sqrt(v^2 + w^2) >= 1;
subject to min_dist_AD: sqrt(x^2+y^2) >= 1;
subject to min_dist_BC: sqrt(v^2+(w-1)^2) >= 1;
subject to min_dist_BD: sqrt(x^2+(y-1)^2) >= 1;
subject to min_dist_CD: sqrt((v-x)^2+(w-y)^2) >= 1;
```

Then I let the [global optimization solver Baron](https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/go:BARON/AMPL.html) solve it:

```
*************************************************************

   NEOS Server Version 5.0

   Disclaimer:

   This information is provided without any express or
   implied warranty. In particular, there is no warranty
   of any kind concerning the fitness of this
   information  for any particular purpose.
*************************************************************
Job 8432228 has finished.
You are using the solver baron.
Checking ampl.mod for baron_options...
Checking ampl.com for baron_options...
Executing AMPL.
processing data.
processing commands.
Executing on prod-exec-6.neos-server.org

4 variables, all nonlinear
5 constraints, all nonlinear; 12 nonzeros
    5 inequality constraints
1 nonlinear objective; 4 nonzeros.

BARON 19.12.7 (2019.12.07): threads=4
BARON 19.12.7 (2019.12.07): 107 iterations, optimal within tolerances.
Objective 5.732032769
v = 0.866025
w = 0.5
x = 0.866026
y = -0.499992
```

This is exactly the solution you obtained. Since Baron found the globally optimal solution, this is proof that you cannot do better.

Comment: By "contract the points", I initially thought you meant "pull these two closer together," but that's not really clear. On the other hand, if you have an arrangement with min distance $q > d$, you can scale-down the entire thing by $(x, y) \mapsto \frac{d}{q}(x, y)$ to get an arrangement with min distance $d$, so your earlier arrangement was not in fact a minimum one. (I know you know this; I'm just adding it for others who, like me, might have been confused).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time. I have already gotten it numerically solved, I should have mentioned it. What I am more interested in is a more "mathematical" proof, or at least I would like some references to understand better why we can't do any better.

Comment: @Axel Baron is a mathematically sound global optimization method. It is not subject to chance like simulated annealing or just locally optimal like gradient descent. The absolute tolerance for feasibility for the solution above is $10^{-5}$ (so the distance between two points can be $0.99999$ instead of $d=1$), and the absolute optimality tolerance is $10^{-6}$, meaning there can't be a solution with a value better than $5.732031769$. These tolerances are user adjustable.

Comment: I trust you and thank you, but this is not the kind of proof I am looking for. I would rather like to know the path to get to the result rather than the result in itself.

Comment: @Axel I could amend my answer and add background information on Baron's algorithm, so you can understand the path to the result.

Comment: @LinAlg Yes please, why not.

Comment: It seems to be that $v, x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $w = \frac{1}{2}$, and $y = -\frac{1}{2}$, which would give $P = 5 + \sqrt{3} \approx 6.732$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Sure, it is. But that's not the point of my original question. I am looking for a written proof.